# Nokia Here Maps Marker Events

Tags: maps, here-api, nokiax

Good Day Devs, how to handle a the marker click event in Here Maps Android? I'm kinda confused on the documentation on how to used the events. Thank you Devs.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember this right, its not really trivial, basically you should get the event that the map was tapped, and then get selected objects for the point, and then see which one is MARKER and then that's the object you are looking for: example included in [Marker Example](https://github.com/DrJukka/NokiaX_Maps/blob/master/HereAPI_v2Porting/src/com/example/hereapi_example/MarkerDemoActivity.java)

Do remember to check other examples from my github: [github.com/DrJukka/NokiaX_Maps](https://github.com/DrJukka/NokiaX_Maps), the v2 porting, illustrates how you can implement the Google maps example included in the Android SDK using HERE API directly.